# R - one scale multiple column recode

Tags: r, statistics, psych

A fellow researcher and I are trying to figure out a way to make our dataframe cleaner, and less cluttered.
Here is a reprex:

```
> head(Dummy1)
# A tibble: 6 x 18
     A0    A1    A2    A3    A4    A5    B0    B1    B2    B3    B4    B5    C0    C1    C2    C3    C4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
2     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
3     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
4     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
5     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
6     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
# … with 1 more variable: C5 <dbl>
>
```

Due to the way our software registered answers, we got A0 through A5, B0 through B5, etc instead of this:

```
> head(Dummy2)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     5     5     5
2     4     4     4
3     3     3     3
4     2     2     2
5     1     1     1
6     0     0     0
>
```

Is there a code that would allow us to transform the first version, each possible answer as a column with a binary 0 NO 1 YES into a single item column with the numeric result? The scale we are trying to analyze has well over 50 items, each ranging from 0 to 8.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split.default` to split all the same group columns in one dataframe. Use `sapply` with `max.col` to get the column number with the highest value in each row. I did `-1` since your column numbers start with 0.

```
sapply(split.default(Dummy1, sub('\\d+', '', names(Dummy1))), max.col) - 1
```

`sub('\\d+', '', names(Dummy1))` removes the number from column names so that they return `"A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "B"......` which is used as a group to split on in `split.default`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this as well:

```
library(tidyverse)

d1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=everything(), names_to='col') %>% 
  # to longer data by taking all columns into 'col', the default for values column is value here , you can change that name, I am sticking with default value
  filter(value != 0) %>% 
  # keep only values having non zero status
  mutate(newval = as.numeric(str_extract(col, '\\d+$')),
         col = str_replace(col, '\\d+','')) %>% 
  ## replace original col by removing their numbers and create another column by only taking the numbers
  select(-value) % >% 
  # removing value column created as its a constant and converting back to wide data then unnesting every column
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from =newval, values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(everything())
```

**Input data:**

```
d1 <- data.frame(A0 = c(0,0,0,0,0,1),
                 A1 = c(0,0,0,0,1,0),
                 A2 = c(0,0,0,1,0,0),
                 A3 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0),
                 A4 = c(0,1,0,0,0,0),
                 A5 = c(1,0,0,0,0,0),
                 B0 = c(0,0,0,0,0,1),
                 B1 = c(0,0,0,0,1,0),
                 B2 = c(0,0,0,1,0,0),
                 B3 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0),
                 B4 = c(0,1,0,0,0,0),
                 B5 = c(1,0,0,0,0,0),
                 C0 = c(0,0,0,0,0,1),
                 C1 = c(0,0,0,0,1,0),
                 C2 = c(0,0,0,1,0,0),
                 C3 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0),
                 C4 = c(0,1,0,0,0,0),
                 C5 = c(1,0,0,0,0,0))
```

**Output**:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     5     5     5
2     4     4     4
3     3     3     3
4     2     2     2
5     1     1     1
6     0     0     0
```